# Searching all emails over large document

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to search for email Ids in a large document using regex.

```
/(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/i
```

The regex is working fine but I need to limit the characters limit after `.` from 3 to 5 characters.

Eg:- for **xyz@gmail.compxhyuidmhs** it must return xyz@gmail **.compx**

Comment: Have you tried changing 3 to 5 here `|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}`?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes I already have